# Compiling SDL2 Error in Terminal (Confused about how to include SDL2 library)

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm learning SDL2 right now and I'm working in XCode for the most part as I code. However, I want to run my program in terminal to use valgrind, but whenever I try, I get this error:

```
fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
```

I'm compiling in a really simple way as follows:

```
g++ Camera.cpp LTexture.cpp LTimer.cpp LWindow.cpp Player.cpp Tile.cpp TileMap.cpp main.cpp -o main
```

I know that I'm supposed to be including the SDL2 library somehow, but I'm unsure of how to do that. Right now, the framework is sitting in the folder /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you have the "SDL2" folder you are trying to include?

Comment: @Desaroll The framework is in /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework. Inside of the frameworks is a folder called "Headers" if that is what you are referring to. There's also an executable called "SDL2" there as well"

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. You are, somewhere in you code, doing a `#include "SDL2/SDL.h" `. Where is the file SDL.h?

Comment: Ah yes my fault. It's found in /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.frameworks/Headers/SDL.h

Comment: If you look your code, it's trying to include "SDL2/SDL.h", but your "SDL.h" is not in a "SDL2" folder. First, you have to fix it. Then, your command should gave the `-I[dir]` option where [dir] is the path to the directory containing the "SDL2" directory.

Comment: add -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.frameworks/Headers to your g++ command and change the 'SDL2/SDL.h' include to just 'SDL.h' since /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.frameworks/Headers doesn't have an SDL2 folder (usually)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
-I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.frameworks/Headers
```

to your g++ command and change

```
'SDL2/SDL.h'
```

include to just

```
'SDL.h'
```

in your header/(s) since `/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.frameworks/Headers` doesn't contain an SDL2 folder (usually)

---

Now that you changed the `#include "SDL2/SDL.h"` to `#include "SDL.h"` you want to go open your Xcode project, select your target, go to build settings and add  `/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.frameworks/Headers` to `Header Search Paths` in order to fix Xcode's 'Couldn't find 'SDL.h'' error message.

---

Update:

Another way would be linking (using ln) `/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.frameworks/Headers` to `/usr/local/include/SDL2`, add `-I/usr/local/include/SDL2` to your g++ command
and leave the `#include` as is (`'SDL2/SDL.h'`)